# Why django order_by has duplicate

Tags: python, django

I write django restframework

I use set to make sure the number only appears one time

```
def hot_movie(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print set(list)    #set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 40, 41, 42, 59, 61, 64, 65, 68, 70, 71, 73, 76, 77])

    self.queryset  = Movie.objects.filter(id__in=set(list)).order_by('hotrank','-releaseday')
    return super(MovieList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But after django order_by(),there is one duplicate ,
is it because paginator??
It shows 10 results in a page.
And in page 2 the id=77 appears again
Please help me!!  I'm stuck many days.

I try `Movie.objects.filter(id__in=set(list)).order_by('-releaseday')` won't duplicate 
But `Movie.objects.filter(id__in=set(list)).order_by('hotrank')` has duplicate! Why would this happen??

Answer (score 2):

If several movies have the same `hotrank` then the real order in `ORDER BY hotrank` is not guaranteed.  Try to add additional field to `order_by()` clause:

```
Movie.objects.filter(id__in=set(list)).order_by('hotrank', '-id')
```

Comment: yes,I have same hotrank.so I can use ````.order_by('hotrank', '-id','-releaseday')```` ?

Comment: It is better to add `-id` to the end of ordered fields - `.order_by('hotrank', '-releaseday', '-id')`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, as described here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6886

The solution seems to be to add the primary key to the ordering, as suggested by oxan in that thread:

```py
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter


# Work around DRF issue #6886 by always adding the primary key as last order field.
class StableOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = super(StableOrderingFilter, self).get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        pk = queryset.model._meta.pk.name

        if ordering is None:
            return (pk, )

        return list(ordering) + [pk]
```